# Extracting text form specific nested nodes with attributes

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to write XPath that will select `<h3>, <ul> and <p>` tags under `div[@class="content"]` but with `p[position() > 1 and position() < last() - 1]`

So far I have this....

```
//div[@class="content"]/*[self::h3 or self::ul or self::p[position() > 1 and position() < last() - 1]]//text()
```

But it doesn't work.

Here's HTML: https://gist.github.com/umrashrf/5167711

Comment: I works in `firebug+firepath`. Did you try `import lxml.html`

Answer (score 0):

OK your XML was not well formed so I fixed this first.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="content">
<h1/>
<h2>
    <p>Certified Nursing Assistant - Full Time</p>
Job Summary</h2>
<p>Responsible for providing personal care and assistance for residents in long    
term care facility.</p>
<h2>
</h2>
<h3>Essential Functions:</h3>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span style="line-height: 1.5;">Responsible</span> for providing   
personal care and assistance to residents </li>
    <li>Assist residents in and out of bed, dressing, feeding, grooming and 
personal hygiene. </li>
    <li>Provide basic treatments as required and directed by nursing staff.  
</li>
    <li>Responsible for observing and reporting changes in residents' physical 
and emotional conditions to charge nurse. </li>
</ul>
<h3>Qualifications: </h3>
<p>Education:</p>
<ul>
    <li>High school diploma or equivalent </li>
    <li>Successful completion of state approved certified nursing assistance 
course </li>
</ul>
<p>Experience:</p>
<ul>
    <li>Previous health care related experience preferred </li>
</ul>
<a id="ctl00_ctl01_namelink" class="btn" href="employment-application.aspx?
positionid=34">Apply Online</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<h2>
Apply in Person</h2>
<p>
To apply in persion please stop by Shenandoah Medical Center to pick up a job 
application.</p>
<h2>
Apply by Mail</h2>
<p>
To apply by mail, download and print <a target="_blank" href="/filesimages/Careers/SMC 
Employment Application.pdf">
    this form</a>. Please fill out the application and then mail to:<br/>
    <br/>
    <strong>Shenandoah Medical Center, Human Resources<br/>
    </strong>300 Pershing Avenue<br/>
Shenandoah, IA 51601</p>
</div>
```

Now if I understand your question correctly, you are looking to find all h3, ul and p tags, which are child nodes of div[@class="content"] and each selected child node must satisfy the condition [position() > 1 and position() < last() - 1]. For this I think this  single XPATH will do:

```
//div[@class="content"]/h3[position() > 1 and position() < last() - 1]  |        
//div[@class="content"]/p[position() > 1 and position() < last() - 1]  |  
//div[@class="content"]/ul[position() > 1 and position() < last() - 1]
```